# Force close application loading images in gridview.builder

Tags: flutter

I'm showing images from an api in a `GridView.builder()` , I tried [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image) package and **Image.network()** but in certain point the application closes itself and shows this error:

```
[        ] Lost connection to device.
[   +1 ms] DevFS: Deleting filesystem on the device
[        ] Sending to VM service: _deleteDevFS({fsName: saving_farmer})
[ +256 ms] Ignored error while cleaning up DevFS: TimeoutException after 0:00:00.250000: Future not completed
```

I don't know what's the best way to show a lot images inside a gridview because the strange thing is that in some devices present this error and others don't.

This is the method when I show the grid:

```
Widget _showGrid2() {
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: _trees.length,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 4,
          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 15.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 15.0,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return GestureDetector(
            child: GridTile(
              child: Image.network(
                _trees[index]["images"][0]["url"],
                // 'https://via.placeholder.com/${index + 1}',
                filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                width: 50.0,
                height: 50.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                    ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                  if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                  return Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 15.0,
                      height: 15.0,
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                        strokeWidth: 2.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              footer: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: Text(
                  _trees[index]["product"]["code"].toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () => _tapPhoto(_trees[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

I'm thinking that probably the error is a problem related with the memory but I'm not sure.

Comment: This issue still exists in the latest `image_picker` package, please write an answer if you found a way to resolve this.